# Selenium test cases execution in maximized browser state

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I want to run my selenium test cases on Chrome/Firefox in maximized state. Currently, I have a pipeline that works and runs my Selenium java tests (mvn test) only in headless mode regardless of the configuration I set in my driver definition. GitLab runner is configured under my VM where all pipeline stages are running. Is there a way or something I am missing with which I can run my tests in a maximized browser state?

Pipeline stage:

```
stages:
  - test_regression_suite

E2E_tests:
  image: maven:3-jdk-11
  stage: test_regression_suite
  tags:
    - ci-runner
  variables:
    JAVA_HOME: "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_361"
  script:
    - cd pth\to\my\framework\src\runner\file
    - mvn test
  timeout: 1200 seconds
  allow_failure: true
```

Browser configurations:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + operatingPlatform);
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[]{"Chrome PDF Viewer"});

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    HashMap<String, Object> options1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options1.put("prefs", prefs);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Despite the option ("--start-maximized") already defined above, it still runs the test cases in the headless mode because of which several of my test cases are getting failed (due to application UI dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

So we connected with the GitLab support team on this and it seems to be a limitation from the runner that it always runs tests in a headless mode regardless of what configurations are applied in the automation framework. Also, this goes for other scripts (PowerShell or ms cmd) and the execution will be done in silent/ headless mode.